# Negative predictions for binomial predictions from gbm in R

Tags: r, boosting

I've just fit a binomial model (training y = 0 or 1) using R's gbm package. When I calculated predicted values using my validation data, some of the predicted values were less than 0.

Is this normal behavior? If so, how do I handle the negative values, floor them at 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I emailed the author of the package, Greg Ridgeway, and got this response:

"Predictions are on the canonical scale, which for binomial us the log-odds scale. You can use the type="response" when predicting to put it on the probability scale."